# DSolve error — fewer dependent variables than equations

Tags: differential-equations

I try to solve this equation:

[image]

And I got an answer:

```
DSolve[k'[t] == s k[t]^a - (n + b) k[t], k[t], t]

{{k[t] -> E^(-6 t) C[1]}}
```

But now I try this:

```
DSolve[{k'[t] == s k[t]^a - (n + b) k[t], k'[t] == 0}, k[t], t]
```

And got an error:

> DSolve: There are fewer dependent variables than equations, so the system is overdetermined.

Please, help me. What should I do?

Comment: Please provide the values of `s,a,n,b`.

Comment: you meant `k'[0] == 0` (not `k'[t] == 0`)?

Comment: s = 0.299, a = 0.35, n = 0.01, b = 0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
s = 0.299; a = 0.35; n = 0.01; b = 0.1; 
K = DSolveValue[{k'[t] == s k[t]^a - (n + b) k[t], k[0] == 0}, k ,t] // Chop
(*Function[{t},0.216305 2.71828^(-0.0715 t) (-1. + 1. 2.71828^(0.0715 t))(2.71828^(-0.0715 t) (-299. + 299. 2.71828^(0.0715 t)))^(7/13)]*)

Plot[K[t], {t, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "k[t]"}]
```

[image]